# How to compile multiple Java files together?

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea

I'm having a problem figuring out how to run a program in intellij IDEA. I'm new to java, coming from C++.

I followed a tutorial to create the game Snake (done in a different IDE). I have 3 files GamePanel.java, GameFrame.java, and SnakeGame.java (this file has the main). I've tried searching up how to compile multiple files and I found one post that says to run

```
java *.java
```

But then I run into a problem of not finding main.

[Error from the terminal code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIr2h.png)

If I just click the build project icon, it says the build is finished but the game doesn't pop up.

The only way I've found to make the game pop up is put all the classes in one file, and then run in the terminal.

```
java filename.java
```

My question is why doesn't the game show up when I press build project?

Comment: Building and running are different things. In IntelliJ  should find a a run icon next to your main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
java *.java
```

with

```
javac *.java
```

`javac` is the command to compile a `.java` file and since you want to apply it to all files, you specify `*.java`.

`javac *.java` compiles all your java files in that folder. In order to run the one with `public static void main`, you need to use `java Foo` where `Foo.java` is the file that has `public static void main`.

**Demo:**

```
[~/Desktop/quickstart]: ls
A.java  B.java  C.java
[~/Desktop/quickstart]: javac *.java
[~/Desktop/quickstart]: ls
A.class A.java  B.class B.java  C.class C.java
[~/Desktop/quickstart]: java C
Hello
Hi
```

---

**A.java:**

```
class A {
    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");        
    }
}
```

**B.java:**

```
class B {
    public void hi() {
        System.out.println("Hi");       
    }
}
```

**C.java:**

```
class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.hello();

        B b = new B();
        b.hi();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, but nothing happens when I type this

Comment: @Esau - `javac *.java` compiles all your java files in that folder. In order to run the one with `public static void main`, you need to use `java Foo` where `Foo.java` is the file that has `public static void main`. I suggest you add a screenshot of your project structure for a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: I tried the java Foo, and I got this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class SnakeGame tried to access method 'void GameFrame.<init>()' (SnakeGame is in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader @1d371b2d; GameFrame is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at SnakeGame.main(SnakeGame.java:5)

Comment: All snakegame.java (foo in your example) is, is this:                   

public class SnakeGame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GameFrame frame = new GameFrame();
        System.out.println("In SnakeGame.java");
    }
}

Comment: You see how I declare an object of GameFrame type? I think that's the problem it doesn't understand what GameFrame is, even though there is a GameFrame.java file in the same folder!

Comment: @Esau - Have you also declared any package in your `.java` file?

Comment: Nope. I tried doing a package earlier but that didn't work earlier so I just put all the files back into the src

Comment: @Esau - Are you doing it from the Terminal window or from some IDE (like Eclipse/IntelliJ etc.)?  If you are already using an IDE, these commands are not required as you can do everything from within the IDE itself.

Comment: I was doing it within the IDE. I know I've been trying forever to get this simple thing to work. I just have to click build project right? When I click it though nothing happens, I'll share a screenshot to show you.. https://imgur.com/a/fgdPKWl

Comment: The game should theoritically pop up when I click Build Project right? Because it pops up when I put all the classes in one file and then do java file.java. This is the part that confuses me..

Comment: That example is what I needed! Thank you. And what does the 'java C' line do? Run an executable file? Because I don't see the C file in the directory. And what exactly are the class files? I'm a noob to Java so I don't know these things. Could you append these answers to the answer?

Comment: @Esau - You are most welcome. You have understood correctly that `java C` runs the executable file (i.e. `C.class`). A class file contains the byte code, compiled from the source code. You can search some articles (e.g. [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compilation-execution-java-program/), [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jcarroll/15-100-s05/supps/basics/history.html) etc.) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

## `javac` tool (compiling) versus `java` tool (executing)

To compile via command-line, use [`javac`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javac) rather than `java`.  See the [documentation for `javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/javac.html).

The `java` tool is for running classes that have already been compiled. For multiple classes, you should put them into a [Java ARchive file (JAR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) file. You include a manifest file that siecifies which class has a `main` method to be used for launching.

As you discovered, Java 11 gained a convenience feature where a single source-code file with a main method can be compiled *and* executed by simply calling `java`. The `javac` tool is implicitly called on your behalf. See [*JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330).

## IDEs

FYI, most of use an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) to do this compiling and packaging for us rather than manually calling the command-line tools. I recommend you do the same.

You have a choice of at least three astoundingly good IDEs, each with a wide-range of features. Listed here in random order:

- [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) by the Apache Foundation
- [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) by the Eclipse Foundation
- [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) by JetBrains

All three are available free-of-cost, with JetBrains also offering a paid *Ultimate* edition in addition to their free *Community* edition.

All three of these tools support using Apache Maven or Apache Gradle as the dependency-management and build-automation tooling. So you can choose to make your project portable across IDEs.

## IntelliJ example

Here is quick tutorial using IntelliJ with Apache Maven.

Choose File > New > Project. In the "New Project" dialog, click *Maven* on the left. Check *Create from archetype*. Scroll down to *org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart*. Expand that item to choose *RELEASE*. Click *Next* button.

Name you project something like *MyFirstDemo*. This is the name of the project folder created on disk. Expand the *Artifact Coordinates*. Change *GroupId* to something for you, like *com.esau.demo*. Convention is to use the reverse of a real domain you own, or invent something unlikely to cause a collision in naming. Change *ArtifactId* to the name of your `.jar` file that we will eventually produce. Perhaps just "MyFirstDemo", but it can differ from project name if you want.

Click *Next* to Maven screen. IntelliJ comes with a copy of Apache Maven bundled. No changes, click *Next*.

Wait a moment as your project is created. This may take a moment as often a [Maven POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) (configuration) file expands itself and then creates the project, and downloads needed libraries.

Edit your POM. I suggest changing:

```xml
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

… to your desired version of Java. Java 16 is current. I am using an early-access version of Java 17 for an Apple Silicon machine. So I use:

```xml
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
```

You will see a tiny floating window centimeter square with a little icon of "M" covered by little double-arrow circle. Click that to same and apply your Maven POM edits. Wait a moment.

Look around for, and click, a "Maven" tab on left, button, or right side of your IntelliJ window. If not there, click in extreme lower-left corner for a pop-up menu. Either way, you should get a *Maven* panel listing the name of your project. Expand that, and expand *Lifecycle* that appears. Of several verbs listed, notice *clean* and *install*. Double-click each of those, waiting a moment in-between. You may need to wait for more stuff to download. Now your app is ready to run. Close the POM file.

In *Project* pane, navigate through your project name to *src* folder, through *main* and so on until you get to *App*. Double-click to open in editor.

You will see a brief class whose key line is:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
}
```

You should see a green triangle icon to the left of that `main` method. Click that icon to display a pop-up menu of several *run* and *debug* items. Choose the first *run* item. You should see the *Run* pane appear, displaying results.

Let's add a file. In *Project* pane, context-click on the `com.esau.demo` package name. Choose *New Java class*. In little window that appears, choose `Record` (for Java 16 or later). In that same box, type `Person`, and press Return/Enter.

If unfamiliar with records, see [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You merely need declare the name and type of the member fields. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

A `Person.java` file is created and opened. Edit to look like this:

```java
package com.esau.demo;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public record Person ( String name , LocalDate hired ) { }
```

Flip back to the `App.java` tab. Edit to look like this:

```java
package com.esau.demo;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        Person alice = new Person( "Alice" , LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) );
        System.out.println( "alice = " + alice );
    }
}
```

Click that green triangle icon on `main` method again. This will cause your code changes to be saved, compiled, and executed.

[image: screenshot of code editor with green-triangle icon to run app]

The `Run` pane shows:

> Hello World!
>
> alice = Person[name=Alice, hired=2020-03-23]

If all that works, go discover your `.jar` file that has been automatically built. In *Project* pane, navigate to *target* folder. Expand to see `MyFirstDemo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Context-click to choose *Open in* > *Finder* (for macOS — choose your OS file manager tool appropriate to your OS such as BSD, Linux, Windows, etc.).

For fun, let's explore inside your `.jar` file. A JAR is actually just a [ZIP file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)). So open with an unzipping utility. On a Mac, change the name to end in `.zip`: `MyFirstDemo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`, and double-click to expand into a new folder named `MyFirstDemo-1.0-SNAPSHOT`. From there, nose around to see the MANIFEST.MF file, and your compiled classes. When done, delete that entire `target` folder, as IntelliJ will re-create it on your next build.

[image: screenshot of folders leading to manifest file]

[image: screenshot of folders leading to pair of class files]

After that, your homework assignment is to study the [*Run/debug configurations*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html) documentation for IntelliJ.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried to do javac  GamePanel.java GameFrame.java SnakeGame.java and while I didn't get an error, nothing happened. And as of right now, I have everything in the source folder, like the tutorial did. All the tutorial had to do is click one button and then the snake game showed up in another window. I thought that's what the 'build project' icon does.

Comment: @Esau I don’t know your specific situation. But I can tell you (a) that IntelliJ depends heavily on context menus, (b) learning to use Maven and its “QuickStart” archetype is worthwhile.

Comment: @Esau I added a mini-tutorial section for you to follow along in an attempt to build a Java app in a JAR with multiple classes.